# open image with Pillow

Tags: python, file-upload, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to user `pillow` to open a POSTed image, but the image starts with:

```
--------------------------332c61f93bcd60b4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="Cat.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿàJFIF``ÿÛC       

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC
```

and finishes with:

```
òeã ý*¥Ô‰åêõš¿yÿCëX×ŸêÛðþtœÈ7pzò+gOŒ'Î{V<Ò¶ô®¯ô?Ê€ ¹fŽb£qÇ¡¢–oõ­EÿÙ
--------------------------332c61f93bcd60b4--
```

the code i'm using is the following:

```
img = Image.open(event["body"].decode('base64')) 
in_mem_file = io.BytesIO() 
img.save(in_mem_file, format="JPEG")
```

in `event["body"]` there is the base64 encoded image with the Content-Disposition, name, filename, and so on.

I have tried to replace the first part and other stuff, but it seems that nothing works.
How i can fix this? thanks

---

UPDATE (fix):

The image must contain just the data, without (also the space must be removed):

```
--------------------------332c61f93bcd60b4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="Cat.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

and

```
--------------------------332c61f93bcd60b4--
```

Comment: Have you tried saving it in a file and then opening that?

Comment: @Colin not really, but i need to open the the file with the header or just the data?

Comment: I can't really help without seeing your code.

Comment: @Colin 
img = Image.open(event["body"].decode('base64'))
        in_mem_file = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(in_mem_file, format="JPEG")

i need to save the file in memory

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: @Colin thx updated

Comment: I don't think you need the second part, just use a temp file.